# Erro na leitura de arquivo

Tags: c, arquivo

Preciso criar funções que leiam de um arquivo de entrada.txt:

- Quantidade de pontos
- Coordenadas dos pontos

---

- Quantidade de linhas
- Número de vértices de cada linha
- Coordenadas de cada vértice da linha

---

- Quantidade de polígonos
- Número de vértices de cada polígono
- Coordenadas de cada vértice do polígono

As funções que criei são:

```
int LeNumeroDePontos()
{
    FILE *entrada;
    entrada = fopen("entrada.txt", "r");
    int nponto;
    printf("Digite a quantidade de pontos que se quer (Maximo 100): ");
    fscanf(entrada, "%d", &nponto);
    return nponto;
}

void LePontos(Ponto **ptemp, int npontos)
{
    FILE *entrada;
    entrada = fopen("entrada.txt", "r");
    int i;
    double x, y;
    *ptemp = (Ponto *) malloc(npontos*sizeof(Ponto));
    Ponto *p = *ptemp;
    printf("Digite as coordenadas X e Y:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < npontos; i++)
    {
        fscanf(entrada, "%lf", &x);
        fscanf(entrada, "%lf", &y);
        criaPonto(&p[i], x, y);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int LeNumeroDeLinhas()
{
    FILE *entrada;
    entrada = fopen("entrada.txt", "r");
    int nlinhas;
    printf("Digite a quantidade de linhas que se quer: ");
    fscanf(entrada, "%d", &nlinhas);
    return nlinhas;
}

int LeNumeroDeVerticesCadaLinha()
{
    FILE *entrada;
    entrada = fopen("entrada.txt", "r");
    int numVertices;
    printf("Digite a quantidade de vertices da linha: ");
    fscanf(entrada, "%d", &numVertices);
    if(numVertices < 2)
        exit(1);
    else
        return numVertices;
}

int LeNumeroDePoligonos()
{
    FILE *entrada;
    entrada = fopen("entrada.txt", "r");
    int npoligonos;
    printf("Digite a quantidade de poligonos que se quer: ");
    fscanf(entrada, "%d", &npoligonos);
    return npoligonos;
}

int LeNumeroDeVerticesCadaPoligono()
{
    FILE *entrada;
    entrada = fopen("entrada.txt", "r");
    int numVertices;
    printf("Digite a quantidade de vertices do poligono: ");
    fscanf(entrada, "%d", &numVertices);
    if(numVertices < 3)
        exit(1);
    else
        return numVertices;
}
```

Quando eu as implementei, porém lendo os dados do teclado, todas funcionavam corretamente. Porém, ao implementar a leitura de arquivo, os dados não são lidos corretamente. Na função principal, tem-se:

```
int main()
{
    FILE *entrada;
    entrada = fopen("entrada.txt", "r");

    int npontos = LeNumeroDePontos();
    LePontos(&Pts, npontos);
    ImprimePontos(Pts, npontos);

    int nlinhas = LeNumeroDeLinhas();
    LeImprimePontosDaLinha(Li, VertLinha, nlinhas);

    int npoligonos = LeNumeroDePoligonos();
    LeImprimePontosDoPoligono(Pol, VertPoligono, npoligonos);

    fclose(entrada);
    return 0;
}
```

Levem em consideração que, na função principal, as variáveis foram devidamente declaradas.

O arquivo de entrada é o seguinte:

```
5     //Numero de pontos
10 5  //Coordenadas de cada ponto
12 4
13 2
2 1
1 0
2     //Numero de Linhas
3     //Numero de vértices da primeira linha
0 0   //Coordenadas dos vértices da primeira linha
1 1
3 6
4     //Numero de vértices da segunda linha
10 17 //Coordenadas dos vértices da segunda linha
22 38
3 0
7 18
1     //Numero de polígonos
4     //Numero de vértices do primeiro polígono
4 9   //Coordenadas do vértice do primeiro polígono
11 3
2 2
5 10
```

Porém, ao pedir para imprimir na tela os valores lidos, tem-se o seguinte resultado:

```
(5, 10)
(5, 12)
(4, 13)
(2, 2)
(1, 1)
```

Essa é a leitura que se repete para todas as outras leituras, ou seja, ele não continua a leitura do restante dos dados. Além disso, o programa para de funcionar.

Gostaria de saber o que pode estar gerando esse problema. Lembrando que não há erro nem aviso após a compilação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está abrindo o arquivo em cada função. Em vez de chamar

```
entrada = fopen("entrada.txt", "r");
```

dentro das funções, você deve passar `entrada` como

```
int LeNumeroDePontos(FILE* entrada) {...}
void LePontos(FILE* entrada, Ponto **ptemp, int npontos) {...}
int LeNumeroDeLinhas(FILE* entrada) {...}
```

---

Cada vez que abre o arquivo, começa a leitura no começo do arquivo. Se passar o `FILE*`, o lugar onde parou de ler será usado para começar a próxima leitura.